# If TAB is pressed can it be triggered as shift + TAB (JQuery, JS)

Tags: html, jquery, input, keypress

I have a HTML List with radio buttons as bullet points. Inside the first list element there is a text Input. The focus is on the Text input.
If I TAB to the next element, even if I set tabindexes it skips the <li> and focuses the next elements after the </ul>.
If I press Shift TAB the focus goes to the previouse <li> element. (Actually I think this is good behavior.)

But I have this one customer who can't press shift+TAB.

Is there a way to manipulate / simulate a key press that it is triggered as Shift keypress?
Is there maybe a pure HTML solution?

> <ul>
> <li><input type='radio'><input type='text'>**this input field has focus**</li>
> <li><input type='radio'>...</li>
> </ul>

I tried some Javascript and JQuery trickery but no luck.

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 9)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        e = jQuery.Event('keypress');
        e.which = 9;
        e.shiftKey = true;
        $('input').trigger(e);
    }
});
```

Does not work in my case. As well as:

```
var evt = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
evt.initKeyEvent('keypress',true, true, window, false, false,false, true, 0, e.keyCode 9);
this.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was a problem with the TAB indexes.
So removing all tabindexes, then setting new tabindexes solved everything.